# ruby regex to check for a valid sentence

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm creating a basic sentence checker that takes a string and determines whether it is valid or not using the following rules

1. The sentence must start with a valid capital letter followed by a lowercase letter
2. All other characters must be lowercase letters
3. There must be a single space between each word
4. The sentence must end with a  terminal mark . or ? or !

I've tried the following code - which covers 1 , 4.  But 2 works  only after the first character

```
puts "Enter your sentence: " 
sentence = gets.chomp

    if (sentence =~ /^[A-Z][a-z0-9_.]\s/ && sentence.end_with?('.','?','!')) 
        puts "Correct >>> " + sentence + " <<< Is a valid sentence!"
    else 
        puts "Incorrect >>>  " + sentence + " Is NOT a valid sentence "
    end
```

Expected result

Enter your sentence: 
Hello!
Correct >>> Hello! <<< Is a valid sentence!

Enter your sentence: 
hello!
Incorrect >>>  hello! Is NOT a valid sentence

Enter your sentence: 
HHello!
Incorrect >>>  HHello! Is NOT a valid sentence

Unexpected result 
HeLlo!
Correct >>> HeLlo! <<< Is a valid sentence!

For single space between each word using \s but it allows more than one space

Comment: What do you consider a "word"? I see you added a dot and an underscore. If you consider words to be lowercase letter chunks, try `/\A\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:\s\p{Ll}+)*[.?!]\z/`

Comment: yes so all other characters must be lowercase letters, separators(, ; :) or terminal marks(, ? !)

Comment: Could you clarify? Do you want to allow any punctuation (but final) before a whitespace? `/\A\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:[\p{P}&&[^?!.]]?\s\p{Ll}+)*[.?!]\z/`? See https://rubular.com/r/MlD0EZI5w8ak6C

Comment: yes to allow punctuation  , ; : or terminal marks . ? !

Comment: Does my regex above work as expected? If you need to only support `,`, `;`, or `:` replace `[\p{P}&&[^?!.]]` with `[,;:]`. See https://rubular.com/r/MkfFz5uvnGhYY7

Comment: what does \p{Lu}\p{Ll} mean?

Comment: `\p{Lu}` - uppercase letter, `\p{Ll}` - lowercase letter.

Comment: Neil, the four rules in your question are unambiguous but  with what you've written in comments above. Also, what is a "valid" capital letter?

Comment: @CarySwoveland What is ambiguous is the `[a-z0-9_.]` in the original regex that does not meet the verbal requirements.

Comment: @Wiktor, as that is part of  the OP's failed attempt to solve the problem, I gave it no weight in parsing the question, especially because the itemised list of requirements is unambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex is only checking for a capital letter, followed immediately by lowercase letter/number/underscore/any character, followed by a space.

You need something that allows for multiple values after the first that meet your criteria. You can use a `+` for this

Here's a sample that meets your test criteria. It doesn't meet your full set of rules, however.

```
def sentence?(sentence)
  sentence = sentence.strip

  if sentence =~ /^[A-Z][a-z0-9_. ]+[\.?!]$/
    puts "  Correct >>> " + sentence + " <<< Is a valid sentence!"
  else
    puts "INCORRECT >>> " + sentence + " Is NOT a valid sentence "
  end
end

sentence?('Hello!') # valid
sentence?('hello!') # not valid
sentence?('HHello!') # not valid
sentence?('HeLlo!') # not valid
```

You can use [rubular](https://rubular.com/r/7xv7erPhXZIQr3) to see how the regex captures various sentences/phrases

Here's something that meets the criteria you described

```
def real_sentence?(sentence)
  sentence = sentence.strip

  if sentence =~ /^[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[a-z]+){0,}[?!\.]$/
    puts "  Correct >>> " + sentence + " <<< Is a valid sentence!"
  else
    puts "INCORRECT >>> " + sentence + " Is NOT a valid sentence "
  end
end

real_sentence?('Hello how are you John?!') # not valid
real_sentence?('hello how are you?') # not valid
real_sentence?('Hello!') # valid
real_sentence?('Hello how are you?') # valid
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I got the downvote, but if someone wants to chime in and provide an explanation that would be great. My original answer didn't include a full solution because the OP's criteria & regex don't match up (regex allows for integers and underscores, but says letters only). It's pretty obvious to me that this is a learning exercise and that they're not trying parse a sentence with limited regex. Hence, I'm not trying to go beyond the problem, just provide enough nudge in the right direction rather than flood them with more complex regex solutions to address criteria not stated